# ToastUtils - helper class for Android SDK Toast

Tags: java, android

Using:

```
ToastUtils.LONG.show(context, R.string.greeting);
```

Code:

```
public class ToastUtils {
    public static ToastUtils LONG = new ToastUtils(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    public static ToastUtils SHORT = new ToastUtils(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    private final int duration;

    private ToastUtils(int duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public Toast makeText(Context context, String text) {
        return Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    }

    public void show(Context context, String text) {
        makeText(context, text).show();
    }

    public Toast makeText(Context context, int resId) {
        return Toast.makeText(context, resId, duration);
    }

    public void show(Context context, int resId) {
        makeText(context, resId).show();
    }

}
```

In my opinion, there are some disadvantages of using `Toast` class directly:

- In `Toast` class I often miss the call to `show()`
- Parameter `length` has type `int`. So a compiler couldn't detect invalid argument value

What do you think? Maybe this class is useless?

Can you suggest any improvements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one important thing missing on your `LONG` and `SHORT` fields.

What if I do `ToastUtils.LONG = null;` ?

That's right, I would break it.

You must specify them as `final`

```
public class ToastUtils {
    public static final ToastUtils LONG = new ToastUtils(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    public static final ToastUtils SHORT = new ToastUtils(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

However, you might just as well change this one and make it an enum

```
public enum ToastUtils {
    LONG(Toast.LENGTH_LONG), SHORT(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    ... // the rest of your code can look the same
```

**But I have to agree with @Kao that your class does not seem to be very useful.**

*It is better to learn the existing API than creating your own API to avoid having to learn the existing API* (Yes, I just made that up. It makes sense though, doesn't it?)

Answer (score 5):

IMO this class isn't very useful (at least in a current shape).

> In Toast class I often miss the call to show()

Well, it's not a bug, it's a feature. There are many situations when you only want to prepare your Toast using `makeText()` and show it later with `show()`.  Moreover, you don't fix this "bug" with your class - there is still a `makeText()` method which does exactly what Toast used to do. And you still can forget to call `show()`.

> Parameter length has type int. So a compiler couldn't detect invalid argument value

I wouldn't say that this is a bug, too. And you're fixing it in a bad way, again:

```
   public static ToastUtils LONG = new ToastUtils(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
   public static ToastUtils SHORT = new ToastUtils(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

So there can only be single instances of `LONG` and `SHORT` at the time. This will make many things complicated.

---

To sum up, this is usage example of your class:

`ToastUtils.LONG.show(context, R.string.greeting);`

And this is the same without using your class:

`Toast.makeText(context, R.string.greeting, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

It's not a big improvement, is it?

Comment: That there can only be one instance of `LONG` and `SHORT` `ToastUtils` should not matter as they are simply factories for creating the real toast.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But this still will make things complicated.

Comment: Yes, overall the class is quite useless